# What does the i18n directory on angular github repo do?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I'm wondering what is the purpose of this directory.

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/i18n

It seems that it is intended to generate the documentation in several languages but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for displaying date, currency and numbers in different formats.

For example: The number pi can be shown as 3.14 for English/US users. While Norwegian users would prefer 3,14 (decimal is separated with comma instead of dot).

Full documentation here: [I18n and L10n in AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)